# How to roll back a video driver from the command line?

Tags: display, greeter, graphic-drivers

I decided to try to install the proprietary nVidia drivers. It should have been the '390 drivers but I installed '340 instead (forgot which graphics card I had). Now, when I reboot, the login screen is something like 800x600 and when I try to log in, I momentarily get a desktop (long enough to see the bluetooth/volume/power/etc/ icons at the top left, but they also seem to be at a low resolution) and then I get dumped back into the login prompt. I can access a terminal via CTL-ALT-F2. So how do I go about reverting back to the nouveau drivers using just the command line?

Comment: Based on my experience reverting from nvidia to nouveau is a difficult job, usually there are a lot of problems after. What I can recommend you to do in this situation is to install the latest nvidia driver by using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and check if everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

An option to revert back is to use AppCenter > Installed, wait until the nvidia drivers become visible on the top, click on the icon of the one that is installed and then uninstall.

Using command prompt only, `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` or `sudo apt remove nvidia-*` . For the first command line option to work probably you have to install purge.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Bo,

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Was the first step in what worked for me. That installed the right set of drivers and at least got me to a desktop, but it turns out that I could only get 640x480 resolution. After this, the nVidia Settings window comes up completely blank (except for Apply and Cancel buttons) and the native System Settings->Displays icon would close System Settings whenever I clicked on it.

```
xrandr -q
```

showed that the system believed 640x480 was the only option available and hence, any attempt to use another was rejected.

In the end, I took a chance on using a previous version of the kernal from the GRUB menu and updated the drivers and resolution from there.

Everything works now. I should have thought of that sooner :-)